# Routing To Sub Directory In MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a folder under Controllers called Api that has a controller named UserApiController.cs.

I am having issues routing to this url.

This file structure looks like this:

- Controllers

  - Api

    - UserApiController.cs

I have set up a new section in the RouteConfig.cs file as seen here:

```
routes.MapRoute(               
name: "Api",
            url: "Api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",

            defaults: new { controller = "UserApi", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
```

I do not seem to be able to access this from the Url /Api/UserApi/Index

My UserApiController.cs file looks like this:

```
namespace OnePlace.Controllers.Api
{

public class UserApiController :Controller

{

    public ContentResult Index()

    {

        return new ContentResult() { Content = "Nothing To See Here", ContentType = "text/html" };

    }

}

}
```

Any help to get this nested content routed would be much appreciated.

Comment: What is error  ? How many routes you have ?

Comment: Is this route before the default route?

Comment: This is the only route except the default route. I have moved it before the default but it is still giving me the error :

"No type was found that matches the controller named 'UserApi'."

When I navigate to:
http://localhost:20311/Api/UserApi/Index

Comment: Ok I managed to figure it out. I should of been navigating to http://localhost:20311/UserApi/Index instead. This is my first time with routing so thank you for your help and consideration.

Answer (score 0):

The code that you've posted looks correct.

However make sure that you are registering the `API` `route` before the other routes.